# How to make a dataframe for kafka streaming using PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am using kafka version 2.11-1.0.1 and Spark version 2.0.2. I have to make a dataframe for kafka response.
So How Can I make dataframe for kafkaStream?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer3", {topic: 1})

lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
@mayankagrawal
Now I want to create a dataframe for this, but I am not able to create.

Answer (score 2):

As you said,

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer3", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

Here, `lines` is a `dStream` of `rdds` and not a single a `rdd` in itself. Hence, to get a dataframe you have to convert it into a `dStream` of dataframes.
Something like this,

```
lines.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.toDF())
```

Comment: lines.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.toDF())
This line throwing following error 

AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'

Comment: For this, you will also have to create a `SQLContext` like `sql = SQLContext(sc)`

Comment: Ok But how to use this SqlContext?

Comment: you dont have to use it anywhere. Dataframe can exist in SQLContext only. That is why you need it.

Comment: Did you find the answer useful?