# Pyspark: Dstream to select columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a Dstream coming from kafka, I want to select columns from it. Following is the code I am implementing but it is giving me errors.

```
import os
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/gsingh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/')
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import sql
import json
import requests


def result(y):
    return y


def handler(rdd):
    records = rdd.collect()

    for record in records:
        producer.send('opportunityProcessed', bytes(record))
        producer.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    findspark.add_packages("org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0")
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

    # os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 pyspark-shell'
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka")
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
    sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)

    print('ssc =================== {} {}')
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'localhost:2181', "spark-streaming-opportunity", {'testing': 1})
    print('contexts =================== {} {}')

    lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])

    lines.foreachRDD(handler)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Right now it is currently reading from kafka and then write into another topic. My objective is to select columns out of the DStream and then have some manipulations on it. So my ptoblem is, it is to how to select columns from DStream?

Comment: you can convert the DStream of rdds to DStream of dataframes and select columns as needed.

Comment: can you provide a snippet of it?

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50446060/7045987)

Comment: I am also getting  AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'. I understand sqlContext has to be used but how?

Comment: You dont have to use it anywhere. Just create a SQLContext and write code normally. Dataframes can exist only in SQLContext.

Comment: Just add `sql = SQLContext(sc)` after creating `sc`.

Comment: So I used this, lines = lines.map(lambda rdd: sql.createDataFrame(rdd)) and it is saying that PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Comment: Dont use `map`. `map` is to apply any function to each record of rdd. You cannot convert a record into a dataframe. You need to use `foreachRDD`.